# page wont load when binding to HTML in Angular 6 project

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

The following angular 6 /bootstrap 4 code will not run

getNumberOfPossibleSteps() returns an array of integers = [ 1,2,3,4]

getDropDownElements() returns an array of options that could be selected for each step
so it returns something like this:

[ "- select an option -", "red option", "blue option", "green option"]

thats why i have the *ngif to select the 0 index by default.

do you see any errors in my code?

```
<div class="container m-4" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 mb-2" id="ddlStep1" *ngFor="let stepnumber of getNumberOfPossibleSteps()">

            <div class="input-group mb-2">

                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">{{ stepnumber }}</span>
                </div>

                <select *ngfor="let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})" id="selectStep{{ stepnumber }}" class="form-control">
                    <!-- choose selected item based on value -->
                    <option *ngif="option == 0" value="{{ stepnumber}}" selected> {{ option }} </option>
                    <option *ngif="option != 0" value="{{ stepnumber}}"> {{ option }} </option>
                </select>

                <div class="input-group-append" id="x">
                    <span class="input-group-text">X</span>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is the console error**

```
vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:37717 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("class="input-group-text"> {{ stepnumber }} </span>
                </div>
                <select [ERROR ->]*ngfor="let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})" id="selectStep{{ stepnumber }}" class="f"): ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:24
Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 36 in [let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})] in ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:24 ("       </div>
                <select *ngfor="let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})" [ERROR ->]id="selectStep{{ stepnumber }}" class="form-control">
                    <!-- choose selected item "): ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:85
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 49 in [let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})] in ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:24 ("       </div>
                <select *ngfor="let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})" [ERROR ->]id="selectStep{{ stepnumber }}" class="form-control">
                    <!-- choose selected item "): ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:85
Parser Error: Unexpected token } at column 49 in [let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})] in ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:24 ("       </div>
                <select *ngfor="let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})" [ERROR ->]id="selectStep{{ stepnumber }}" class="form-control">
                    <!-- choose selected item "): ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:85
Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 50 in [let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})] in ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:24 ("       </div>
                <select *ngfor="let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})" [ERROR ->]id="selectStep{{ stepnumber }}" class="form-control">
                    <!-- choose selected item "): ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:85
Parser Error: Unexpected token ), expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 51 in [elelet option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})] in ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:24 ("       </div>
                <select *ngfor="let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})" [ERROR ->]id="selectStep{{ stepnumber }}" class="form-control">
                    <!-- choose selected item "): ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:85
Can't bind to '*ngfor' since it isn't a known property of 'select'. ("class="input-group-text"> {{ stepnumber }} </span>
                </div>
                <select [ERROR ->]*ngfor="let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})" id="selectStep{{ stepnumber }}" class="f"): ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:24
Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 36 in [let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})] in ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:24 ("ol">
                    <!-- choose selected item based on value -->
                    <option [ERROR ->]*ngif="option == '- Select -' " value="{{ stepnumber}}" selected> {{ option }} </option>
           "): ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@13:28
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 49 in [let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})] in ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:24 ("ol">
                    <!-- choose selected item based on value -->
                    <option [ERROR ->]*ngif="option == '- Select -' " value="{{ stepnumber}}" selected> {{ option }} </option>
           "): ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@13:28
Parser Error: Unexpected token } at column 49 in [let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})] in ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:24 ("ol">
                    <!-- choose selected item based on value -->
                    <option [ERROR ->]*ngif="option == '- Select -' " value="{{ stepnumber}}" selected> {{ option }} </option>
           "): ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@13:28
Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 50 in [let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})] in ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:24 ("ol">
                    <!-- choose selected item based on value -->
                    <option [ERROR ->]*ngif="option == '- Select -' " value="{{ stepnumber}}" selected> {{ option }} </option>
           "): ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@13:28
Parser Error: Unexpected token ), expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 51 in [let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})] in ng:///elephantModule/elephantComponent.html@11:24 ("ol">
                    <!-- choose selected item based on value -->
                    <option [ERROR ->]*ngif="option == '- Select -' " value="{{ stepnumber}}" selected> {{ option }} </option>
           "): ng:///Pvendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:37717)
    at TemplateParser.parse (vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:48814)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:63017)
    at vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:62936
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:62936)
    at vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:62823
    at Object.then (vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:37706)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:62822)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:62751)
syntaxError @ vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:37717
TemplateParser.parse @ vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:48814
JitCompiler._compileTemplate @ vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:63017
(anonymous) @ vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:62936
JitCompiler._compileComponents @ vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:62936
(anonymous) @ vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:62823
then @ vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:37706
JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:62822
JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:62751
PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @ vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:15656
PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ vendor.js?v=MhFn_ZxtXjEPXCyqBgYBRR4wfkygFC59OgfbwTJj73c:15642
(anonymous) @ boot.browser.ts:23
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 32316c84592730b688c7:657
fn @ bootstrap 32316c84592730b688c7:85
(anonymous) @ main-client.js?v=C23MaLEi6jH_pDS4tY7qPVBb0UxKZ-XAo6ef-eCU9s4:329582
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 32316c84592730b688c7:657
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 32316c84592730b688c7:706
(anonymous) @ bootstrap 32316c84592730b688c7:706
client.js:67 [HMR] connected
```

Comment: Try `*ngFor="let option of getDropDownElements(stepnumber)"` (make sure to have to correct casing for `ngFor` and for `ngIf`).

Comment: It's not really possible to tell entirely with what you've given us, since it's lacking the function that you're passing an undefined value to. That said, you can open up your code and ctrl + f for `.toUpperCase` and it will lead you directly to the value that's failing to be passed in properly. Work backwards from there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide your component code ?
I'am not sure that you can do this

```
let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})
```

Can you replace it by this

```
let option of getDropDownElements(stepnumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what getDropDownElements is doing, so perhaps provide the component code. I can, however, see a few problems

Curly brackets are not needed when passing a value to `ngFor` so you can change

```
*ngfor="let option of getDropDownElements({{ stepnumber }})"
```

to

```
*ngfor="let option of getDropDownElements(stepnumber)"
```

You should also be able to add square brackets to properties of HTML elements to indicate that you are using an Angular variable or function, so you can change

```
id="selectStep{{ stepnumber }}"
```

to

```
[id]="selectStep(stepnumber)"
```